# Ropsten Ethereum Coins

Tags: ropsten

I was sent more than $16000 of Testnet Ropsten Ethereum in a Coinbase wallet app. Then was asked to pay $1500 to activate it, so I can cash it to my own bank account. This is a scam, right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a scam.

All testnet coins (Ropsten, Goerli, Kovan, etc.) have no value at all.

Don't listen or trust anyone asking you for money (fiat or crypto) to buy or redeem test coins.

And in general, don't trust anyone asking you money at all ;)